# Apply function to Dataframe GroupBy Object and return dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do I return a dataframe from a groupby object using Pandas? The intent here is to read in a CSV and replace each IP address in the IP address column with a value returned by randIP(). I'd like to do this by grouping to maintain consistency throughout the obfuscated dataframe afterwards (each real IP maps to a new random IP).

I've tried numerous methods but this seems to be the most successful. self.df2 is printing as a pandas.core.grouby.SeriesGroupBy object.

```
def __init__(self, filename):
    self.df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    self.grouped = self.df.groupby('IP Address')
    self.df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    for i, k in self.grouped:
        r = randIP()
        k['IP Address'] = k['IP Address'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(x, r))
    self.df2 = self.grouped
    print(self.df2['IP Address'])
```

Comment: Are you saying you have a DataFrame with an "IP Address" column and you want to return the same DataFrame but with that one column modified?  Is there anything other text in the "IP Address" column besides the IP address?

Comment: That's correct. I have a column of just IP addresses that I would like to replace in a group-wise fashion and return the modified (full) data frame at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better not to try to modify the DataFrame from inside the grouping operation.  Instead, use the grouping operation to *create* the new IPs, then use `map` to map the old IPs to the new ones, and then (if you want) assign the new ones back into the DataFrame:

```
def randomIP():
    return ".".join(str(np.random.randint(0, 255) for it in xrange(4)))

>>> d = pandas.DataFrame({'IP': ['1.2.3.4', '5.6.7.8', '1.2.3.4', '5.6.7.8', '9.10.11.12', '13.14.15.16'], 'Other': ['blah']*6})
>>> d
            IP Other
0      1.2.3.4  blah
1      5.6.7.8  blah
2      1.2.3.4  blah
3      5.6.7.8  blah
4   9.10.11.12  blah
5  13.14.15.16  blah
```

Using `groupby` with `apply` will give you a Series mapping old to new IPs:

```
>>> d.groupby('IP').apply(lambda g: randomIP())
IP
1.2.3.4           4.183.193.46
13.14.15.16    186.124.189.188
5.6.7.8          152.24.105.42
9.10.11.12      188.140.91.209
```

Using `map` on the old IP column and passing this new Series will map old IPs to new IPs:

```
>>> d.IP.map(d.groupby('IP').apply(lambda g: randomIP()))
0    47.227.125.190
1      164.86.98.48
2    47.227.125.190
3      164.86.98.48
4     44.150.90.127
5     71.111.59.115
Name: IP, dtype: object
```

If you want to reassign them back into the DataFrame column, you can do that:

```
>>> d['IP'] = d.IP.map(d.groupby('IP').apply(lambda g: randomIP()))
>>> d
               IP Other
0  238.227.204.61  blah
1   13.201.160.89  blah
2  238.227.204.61  blah
3   13.201.160.89  blah
4    69.33.243.79  blah
5  164.120.13.218  blah
```

I think this last one is the all-in-one solution you're looking for.  (In these examples the random IPs are different every time because I'm calling `randomIP` again in each part of the example.)

Comment: The last example is _perfect_ and the ones above it are highly illustrative of why it works the way it does. Thank you!